# Select a correct voltage controlled oscillator IC

Tags: frequency, oscillation, vco

I need to generate a sine signal using a VCO (voltage controlled oscillator) in order to feed a PLL (Phase-locked loop). I need the output to be 12.8MHz and 3.3Vp-p.

I bought at RS a [VCO reference 7099357](https://es.rs-online.com/web/p/osciladores-controlados-por-tension/7099357/)

Despite the datasheet says: "Output Level (CMOS) Output High (Logic “1”) - - 90% VDD" I can only have an output of 1.2Vp-p. Output frequency is 12.8 as expected. The IC is being feed with 3.3V DC.

What feature do I need to look at in order to select a componen that has the desired 3.3Vp-p output? Do you know any specific component I should use?

This is how I'm connecting the IC

[image]

[VCO (RS-7099357) datasheet](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0e32/0900766b80e32cf6.pdf)

Comment: Are you seeing the output with a scope or just measuring the frequency? Maybe you are exceeding the maximum output load capacitance, i.e. 15pF. That enable pin then, are you sure it goes to Vdd? I think it's more a mode select pin and should be connected to ground for normal operation.

Comment: I'm measuring with a scope. I try to ground or open EN (pin 1) but I get the same result output: 1.2 peak to peak volts. The PPL needs 3.3Vp-p to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using a VCO (variable) if you only need a fixed frequency?

In any case, according to the datasheet you linked, pin 1 should never be connected to VDD. In the VCTCXO variation, this is the control voltage, which must remain between 0.5 and 2.5 V. In the plain TCXO variation, it should either be left open or grounded.

Comment: Ya just beat me to it! This definitely looks like the culprit.

Comment: Yeah, what I can't get is why the frequency is correct. And what about the clipped sine wave output? How can one achieve that? I'd find useful a bit of informations more.

Comment: Exactly how are you measuring the output voltage and frequency?

Comment: @DaveTweed I'm using a scope to mesure the output. I try to ground or open EN (pin1) and I get the same result 1.2Vp-p at the output.

Even if I go from 0.5V to 2.5V in the PIN1 I don't get different frequency...

To tell you the truth I'm using VCO because I'm using an evaluation kit from TI http://www.ti.com/tool/SERDESUB-16OVT and I'm replacing the component they use to feed the PLL witch I guessed it was a VCO. Should I better use something like Wien bridge if I want a fixed frequency?

Comment: @DaveTweed I cannot know if the IC i'm replacing is a VCO since I don't have any reference from the componen, I don't really know if it's a VCO or some kind of oscillator IC. What I know is that the attached picture is the actual schematic and that it outputs 30MHz and 3.3Vp-p. I'm just trying to feed the PLL with a lower frequency

Comment: It's just an oscillator module, but the BOM in the evaluation kit manual just denotes it as "OSC4/SM". You should try to determine whether the original 27 MHz part has some sort of manufacturer's logo on it, track it down and order a 12.8 MHz part from the same family.

Comment: I already Had a response from TI. The oscillator is ASFL1-27.000MHZ-EK-T by Abracon http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ASFL1-27.000MHZ-EK-T/535-9263-2-ND/675458